# Usage of Xmark in the screen

Tags: c#

Goal:
When a user click a exit button in the file > exit or X mark (in the uppright corner of the program's screen) I want a messsage display with comments.

Problem:
How shall I connect "exit button" and "Xmark" into same method that ask about a popup message?

I know how to use the component "menustrip" but not the xmark's sourcecode in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Winforms use the [`Form.Closing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing.aspx) event, in WPF use the [`Window.Closing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing.aspx) event to display your message when the form/window is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Closing` event on your main form, this one happends before the application is actually closed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Form_Closing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing.aspx) event. Clicking on exit, or XMark will raise this event, so you can perform any action here.